# DLIB document summarizing

Tags: dlib

Is there any document that summarizes Davis King's DLIB because it's so extensive that it's practically impossible to know everything it contains? It's the best C++ library I've ever encountered, but it's so extensive that it becomes impossible to know what it has to offer.

For example, dlib::timing, it's not easy to know that this exists.

I tried to generate a PDF document using Doxygen and couldn't.